# Using UTF-8 in C compiler

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I am new to C programming and I have a task to do. My homework is exactly this:

> Assume that you scan the input text in Turkish character by character from the keyboard, which you may think of as a default input device, until a ‘CTRL-D’  is pressed. You are supposed to skip punctuation characters as well as blank character. Your program will display the frequencies of letters and digits whenever the scanning process is done. You need to discuss the data structure as well as flowchart solution and hand in them with your code.

I coded the program but I have a problem. Some characters entered (eg `ğ`) are shown as `§`. Here is my source code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    char message[100] = { ' ' };
    char ch;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");

    printf("Enter your message: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\4')
    {
        message[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        int repeated = 1;

        for (int k = (j + 1); k <= i; k++)
        {
            if (message[k] == message[j])
            {
                repeated++;
            }
        }
        printf("%c is repeated %d times.\n", message[j], repeated);
        while (message[j] == message[j + 1])
        {
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`ğ` is a multibyte character (occupies 2 bytes) and you can't print it with `%c` nor count it as a normal one (2 bytes must be skipped when looping).

But you don't need to do that, C provides libraries to deal with multibyte characters.

You can use `wchar_t` instead of `char`, also replace `getchar` with `getwchar` and `printf` with `wprintf`, finally, note that all string literals are suffixed with `L` and characters are printed using the `%lc` format specifier.

Your code working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    #define N 100
    wchar_t message[N];
    struct
    {
        wchar_t value;
        int count; 
    } letters[N] = {{0, 0}};

    wprintf(L"Enter your message:\n");

    wint_t ch;
    int len = 0;

    while ((ch = getwchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (len < N)
        {
            message[len++] = ch;
        }
    }

    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int j;

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (letters[j].value == message[i])
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == n)
        {
            letters[j].value = message[i];
            n++;
        }
        letters[j].count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        wprintf(L"%lc is repeated %d times.\n", letters[i].value, letters[i].count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all but I have still same problem.

Comment: What problem? You still see `§` instead of `ğ`?

Comment: Yes. When I print ğ, I see §.

Comment: I must be submitted this assignment 2 days later pls help me.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? cmd?

Comment: If you are using "Raster font" on cmd.exe, switch to a Unicode TrueType font (eg. "Lucida Console"), also, save your source file in UTF8.

Comment: I switched it to "Lucida console" but I have still same problem. I dont know  how can I save it in UTF-8.

Comment: Open your .c file with an editor, select "Save as" and choose UTF8

Comment: I did it but I have still same problem. I dont know what is wrong? If u want I can this project to u?

Comment: Is working for me, test it yourself here: https://ideone.com/H2e8bi , problem should be in your console configuration. Have you tried in the PowerShell?

Comment: When I try to run it, I get this error. https://imgur.com/a/DxJ6mqk

Comment: Ohh ok I got this. But I have 1 more problem. As u see program says mutiple time ğ repeated. I want to write the number of repeats 1 time for each letter. Can u help me about this?

Comment: hahah, I left this as an exercise for you ;) try it a little bit and if you have problems ping me and I help you

Comment: :D Thank u sir. I'm wondering if I write a comment like I wrote at the moment, do I tag you or should I write something in the style of @name ..?

Comment: Yes, send another comment here, but try it please, is not difficult at all

Comment: @root_roxox edited, now the code does what you want: the number of repeats 1 time for each letter

Comment: @David Ranieri Ohh thanks man. I tried to correct it, I almost succeeded, but I did not correct the repetition for the last letter. Thanks to you, I can deliver a proper assignment. I owe you.